# Summer18 - Custom Modal Issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, modal, summer-18

i noticed an issue in my summer18 sandbox and can´t find any css changes in the release notes of summer18 that could be responsible for that.

The issue: Background of the page behind a custom modal component:

Before summer 18 (production):
[image: beforesummer18]

After summer 18 (sandbox):
[image]

Its not depending on where the modal component is placed. Same issue with any other custom coded modal.

Does anybody know what changed?

Blank code example:

```
<aura:component controller="xyz" access="global">

<aura:attribute name="title" type="String" required="true" />
<aura:attribute name="closable" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<aura:attribute name="confirmLabel" type="String" default="abbrechen" />

<aura:attribute name="onclose" type="Aura.Action" default="{!c.defaultCloseAction}" />
<aura:attribute name="onconfirm" type="Aura.Action" default="{!c.defaultCloseAction}" />
<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.waiting}" />
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.doneWaiting}" />

<div class="slds">
    <form class="slds-form_stacked">
        <div>
            <div aria-hidden="false" aria-modal="true" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">

                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <div class="slds-modal__header">
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">{!v.title}</h2>
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.closable}">
                            <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-modal__close" iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="Close" size="large" variant="bare-inverse" onclick="{!v.onclose}" />
                        </aura:if>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-button_brand" type="button" onclick="{!v.onconfirm}">{!v.confirmLabel}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal-backdrop slds-modal-backdrop_open"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you!